# cannot add item from connected list to sortable list

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have connected sortable list **A** and **B**. One item is fixed in **list A** called `forbidden` so that it cannot be sorted. When **list A** is empty (only with **forbidden** left) and trying to add item from **list B**, the item always get inserted after the fixed item (**forbidden**) in **list A**. I want it before fixed item (**forbidden**) in **list A**. I want it using jquery-ui-sortable without using any plugins.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/a5dvbhj2/1/)

***#UPDATE***

Check this image. **Isabelle** from **list B** can be placed under **forbidden** when **list A** is empty (i.e, when **list A** contain only **forbidden** [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by [cancel](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel) option and [cancle method](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-cancel) like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".list-A, .list-B").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
      if ($(this).find('.forbidden').length > 0) {    
        if ($('.forbidden').index() < $(this).children().length - 1)
          $('.sortable').sortable("cancel");
      }
    },
    connectWith: ".sortable",
    cancel: '.forbidden'
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

**[Online demo (fiddleJs)](http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/yw18pkm3/)**

Comment: It's not working. As per your fiddle you can place item after **forbidden**. My point is i want **forbidden** to be the last element always even while sorting.

Comment: @melvin So, I am a little bit confused about your question. If you want `forbidden` be last item, the fiddle in your question is true!

Comment: I want it even when sorting. No elements from list B should be able to place below forbidden

Comment: See image in my question @Ali

Comment: @melvin I got you. I edited my answer and updated my fiddle. Please see it again.

Comment: This solves the issue that no item from **list B** can be placed after forbidden in **list  A**.  But still any item from **list A** can be placed after **forbidden**

Comment: @melvin I fixed it. Please see my fiddle again. We need to use `$('.sortable').sortable("cancel");` for fixing it.